# Android: listen to the auxiliary port

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, audiorecord

I am looking for a way to have an Android application listen to a signal coming in from the **auxiliary** port and immediately play it back. Usually this port would be used as an *output* for sound (headphones) but I need it to *listen* instead (more like a microphone). My end goal is to connect a male to male auxiliary (audio) cable from my TV's headphones jack to the android device's headphones jack. Then, I need to have an application that can broadcast that *input* (from the TV) to some Bluetooth headphones. So my question is, how can I set a listener for the headphones jack and immediately play back that audio which is received/recorded?

Things I have looked into - 
[Audio Recording](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html), [Audio Track](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html)

Comment: "Usually this port would be used as an output for sound (headphones)" -- well, for most Android mobile devices, the headset jack supports both. That is why wired headsets work. There are Y cables that supply separate jacks for the input and output signals and merge them into a single plug for the device's headset jack. Get one of those, then use the stuff that you linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out it is essential thay you understand AudioRecord and AudioTrack classes from your link and play with some examples.

One idea comes to my mind. Actually it is possible to play some sounds using audiotrack class which will let you not to worry about AudioRecord at first instance. Using Audio Track you can generate your own samples and play them back. By the nature of a waveform you can play them back and each will have different sounds. There are online tone generators, you can check it out if you want to understand me better  http://onlinetonegenerator.com/ Generating samples that represent those soundwaves can be the first step since you will be able to hear them from your phone.

After that you should start "playing with the connection between bluetooth devices and the phone. Once you know how do the soundwave works you can try to send that file through bluetooth protocol to the device and check if it works.

The way you communicate between any action from an asyncTask to another thing in the main thread is through the publishProgress(nameOfTheSample), so while using bluetooth conection you should take the samples from there.

Once you are done with that you can worry about the sound from the TV.

```
    private class GenerateSamples extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    final int SAMPLE_RATE = 8000;
    int minSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE,
    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLE_RATE,
    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
    minSize,
    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    audioTrack.play();

    short[] buffer = {
    8130,15752,22389,27625,31134,32695,32210,29711,25354,19410,12253,
    4329,-3865,-11818,-19032,-25055,-29511,-32121,-32722,-31276,-27874,
    -22728,-16160,-8582,-466
    };

    while (isPlaying) {
    audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    }
    return null;
       }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, using some of your code along with some other stuff I was able to do what I asked about in the question. However, I still cannot get the Bluetooth part of it to work. Any more advice on that? @eduardo92